# Converts a query which uses exists/not exists to a three table join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on a problem statement where I need to retain records based on a logic which is being applied on three tables.The tables are listed as below.

Table_A:

| id | phone_number | account_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 80001 | 1001 |

Table_B

| id | phone_number | account_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 80002 | 1002 |

Table_C

| id | phone_number | account_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 80003 | 1003 |

I wrote a query as shown below:

```
select /*+PARALLEL(su,8)*/ 
       su.ID 
from TableA su 
where (   EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                         PHONE_NUMBER 
                  from TableB sa
                  where PHONE_NUMBER=su.PHONE_NUMBER
                 )
       or EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                         PHONE_NUMBER
                  from TableC sa
                  where PHONE_NUMBER=su.PHONE_NUMBER
                 )
      )
  and (   EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                         ACCOUNT_NAME
                  from TableB sa
                  where ACCOUNT_NAME=su.ACCOUNT_NAME
                 )
       or EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                         ACCOUNT_NAME
                  from TableC sa 
                  where ACCOUNT_NAME=su.ACCOUNT_NAME
                 )
      )
and NOT EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/ 
                       ID 
                from TableC sa
                where ID=su.ID
               )
and NOT EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/ 
                       ID
                from TableB sa
                where ID=su.ID
               );
```

My requirement here is that for a record of table A if the phone_number and account_name are either in TableB or TableC and the ID is not present in any of these two tables then the record should be present.The existing code works in most of the scenarios but there is a specific scenario where it is not working where for a specific record of table A the acccount_name and phone_number is present for two different records in either of TableB or TableC.I want to exclude these kind of records from my output hence I tried converting my query to a three way join so that the join in on specific records.
The query which I wrote is as below-

```
select su.id
from TableA su,
     TableB sa,
     TableC sb
where (   su.PHONE_NUMBER=sa.PHONE_NUMBER
       OR su.PHONE_NUMBER=sb.PHONE_NUMBER
      ) 
  and (su.ACCOUNT_NAME=sa.ACCOUNT_NAME
       OR su.ACCOUNT_NAME=sb.ACCOUNT_NAME
      ) 
   and NOT EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                          id 
                   from TableC sa 
                   where id=su.id
                  )
   and NOT EXISTS (select /*+ PARALLEL(sa,8) PARALLEL(su,8)*/
                          id 
                   from TableB sa 
                   where id=su.id
                  )
```

This query is returning a number of duplicates and I tried using distinct as well but I am still getting incorrect results.

Could anyone suggest what is wrong on my query? Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I don't fully understand yet. You want to show A rows. But only if the phone number and account name exists in B or C. Are you talking about finding the phone number and account name separately or do you mean that the phone/account pair must exist in at least one of the tables? Then you say the ID must neither be in B nor in C. Does this refer to the whole tables or do you mean the IDs of the rows with the same phone number and account name?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for responding.The dataset which I have is having multiple records with phone/account pair with unique ids.I need to filter out the pairs which do not have a matching id in table A.I am facing the issue in the first query only because I need the match in pairs but since I am using exists/not exists the filter is based on all the records and I am getting the match of two different records.

Comment: @marc_s, I saw and write a lot of code using list of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understand what you require. Here is a query that finds TableA rows where there exists a row in TableB or TableC with the same ACCOUNT_NAME / PHONE_NUMBER pair but a different ID.

```
select *
from tablea a
where exists
(
  select null
  from tableb b
  where b.phone_number = a.phone_number
    and b.account_name = a.account_name
    and b.id <> a.id
)
or exists
(
  select null
  from tablec c
  where c.phone_number = a.phone_number
    and c.account_name = a.account_name
    and c.id <> a.id
)
order by id;
```

If you want to see the other IDs, you must join instead. I suggest a union of TableB and TableC for this:

```
select a.*, bc.table_name, bc.id as other_table_id
from tablea a
join
(
  select 'TableB' as table_name, id, phone_number, account_name from tableb
  union all
  select 'TableC' as table_name, id, phone_number, account_name from tablec
) bc on bc.phone_number = a.phone_number
    and bc.account_name = a.account_name
    and bc.id <> a.id
order by a.id, bc.table_name, bc.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.I used the second query with a slight variation where I used union in place of union all and I got my desired resultset.

Comment: I am glad this worked for you. If it's just about the ID regardless of the table, then `UNION` is indeed appropriate. If you wanted to show the table name, as I did, `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` wouldn't make sense, because there would be no duplicates to remove.